# Why not simply put " It is a kind of insect." to " It is an insect"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, spoken-english, sentence-choice

I stumbled upon a sentence in my reference book. It states that:

> ***It is a kind of insect.***

Is there any specific reason for the author to use that kind of sentence construction?

Wouldn't be easier to simply put:

> ***It is an insect.***

Or am I the one missing something?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the paragraph and surrounding context. There are many kinds of insects: some fly, some crawl, and some hop.

Comment: @J.R. Indeed. That makes sense.

Comment: You could edit your question, then, and make it more clear. By the way, here is some helpful reading, found on our meta site: [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439), [_Are Thanks for Answers Unnecessary?_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744),  and [_When Should I Accept an Answer?_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kind** is used here as a noun to mean a group with similar characteristics, or a particular Ref..

As J.R. mentioned, kind could mean the hopping, flying, crawling kind, or it could mean it's a type of beetle, fly or ant.

There isn't a lot of difference in the context given but the following situation may explain better.

> Ben has a bug called Geoff.
>
> Ben's friend Stu comes over.
>
> Stu "Is Geoff an insect?"
>
> Ben "Yes."
>
> Stu "What kind of insect?"
>
> Ben "Geoff is a beetle."

---

Edit

I just realised there would be a context in which your above example would make a difference!

> Stu "What is a beetle?"
>
> Ben "It is a kind of insect."

Vs

> Stu "What is Geoff"
>
> Ben "Geoff is an insect."

Comment: The illustration seems to help a lot in explaining 'kind', and why it is required in some contexts.

Comment: Glad I could help!